# Spring Data and MongoDB, insert or update

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am using Spring Data  with MongoDB. Is it possible to do something like insert or update for my objects. I am using MongoTemplate and MongoOperation classes.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably want upsert: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.upserts

Comment: It looks good for a field or some fields, but is it possible to do insertorupdate for all object? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm the best way atm is to loop through the upsert, there is no sort of batch upsert/insert functionality atm only batch insert

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB you can [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/create/), [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-update) and [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#upsert) documents.

#### From the MongoDB docs:

*"An upsert eliminates the need to perform a separate database call to check for the existence of a record before performing either an update or an insert operation."*

In simpler terms, this can be thought of *"If and only if this document does not exist already, go ahead and make it for me"*

It should be noted that an upsert will **NOT** happen unless you have set upsert to be true, like in this example from [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/create/#crud-create-update)

```
db.collection.update( <query>,
                  <update>,
                  { upsert: true } )
```

Comment: That answer does not seem to answer the Spring part.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to MongoDB, coming from MySQL/Hibernate/JPA.  In Mongo, its my understanding there is no such thing as an "update" vs. an "insert".  If the id field is the same as something already in the DB, its an update.  If its not, its an insert.

I know in my code, the way I solved having duplicates is by marking my own ID field with @Id.  This tells Spring Data/MongoDB that a particular field should be used in place of the default generated id field.  Thus, if you then attempt to save a entity using the same id, Mongo simply overwrites it.

Answer (score -1):

Spring data have a list of perfect tutorials how to use it with mongodb. You could find in on the [official website](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb)

I started to work with Spring Data via [this tutorial](http://blog.jeroenreijn.com/2011/07/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-spring.html)