# how to insert mongodb document in springframework

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I have a some questions.
I have made application about scan web vulnerability on web page.
 
I have applied spring mvc pattern to my application.
My application consist of controller and service and business object(made python) and DAO(used MongoDB) and DTO.
Business Object is main module that made python language to scan web vulnerability.
The flow of My application as follows.
web page(insert target url for scan vulnerability) -> controller(passed url) -> service(passed url) ->business object(scan web vulnerabilities and return results to service) -> DAO(save results to MongoDB)

The data which return results in Business Object saved each DTO(Total 3 DTO).
Each DTO as follows.

```
//scaninfoDTO
@Document(collection = "scanresult")
public class scanInfoDTO {
@Id
private String _id;

private String url;
private String date;
private String code;

public scanInfoDTO() {
    super();

}

public scanInfoDTO(String url, String date, String _id, String code) {
    super();
    this._id = _id;
    this.url = url;
    this.date = date;
    this.code = code;
}
 below getter/setter method 
 ....
```

scaninfoDTO save url,date and objectid.

```
//forminfoDTO
@Document(collection = "scanresult")
public class formInfoDTO {
@Id
String _id;
private String form_name;
private String tagid;

public formInfoDTO() {
    super();
}

public formInfoDTO(String form_name, String tagid,String _id) {
    super();
    this._id = _id;
    this.form_name = form_name;
    this.tagid = tagid;
}
//below getter/setter method
```

forminfoDTO save formname, tagid and objectid.

```
//vulinfoDTO
@Document(collection = "scanresult")
public class vulInfoDTO {

@Id
String _id;

private String vul_name;
private String patterm_id;
private String pattern;
private String pattern_dspt;
private String code;

public vulInfoDTO() {
    super();
}

public vulInfoDTO(String vul_name, String patterm_id, String pattern, String pattern_dspt, String _id,
        String code) {
    super();
    this._id = _id;
    this.vul_name = vul_name;
    this.patterm_id = patterm_id;
    this.pattern = pattern;
    this.pattern_dspt = pattern_dspt;
    this.code = code;
}
// below getter/setter method
```

vulinfoDTO save vulname, patternid, pattern, patterndesp and code.

```
public class scanDTO {

private formInfoDTO forminfo;
private scanInfoDTO scaninfo;
private List<vulInfoDTO> vulinfo;

public scanDTO() {

}

public scanDTO(scanInfoDTO scaninfo, formInfoDTO forminfo, List<vulInfoDTO> vulinfo) {
    super();
    this.forminfo = forminfo;
    this.scaninfo = scaninfo;
    this.vulinfo = vulinfo;
}
```

and then 3 DTOs which included results in business object merge scanDTO and passed service.

```
@Service
public class ScannerServiceImpl implements ScannerService {

@Qualifier("dao")
@Autowired
ScannerDAO dao;

@Override
public void process_run(String url) {

    //create business object
    ScanningUrl scanBl = new ScanningUrl();
    //url passed to business object and save the results to scanDTO. 
    scanDTO result = scanBl.scan(url);
    System.out.println("process_run end!!!");

    //extract each dto from scanDTO result and save each dto
    scanInfoDTO scan = result.getScaninfo();
    formInfoDTO form = result.getForminfo();
    List<vulInfoDTO> vulne = result.getVulinfo();


    System.out.println("[service][scaninfo] url: "+scan.getUrl()+"date: "+scan.getDate());
    System.out.println("[service][forminfo] form_name: "+form.getForm_name()+" tagid: "+form.getTagid()+" code: "+form.get_id());
    System.out.println("[service][vulinfo] "+vulne.size());

    //Each dto which saved result passed DAO
    dao.scanInsert(scan);
    //dao.vulListInsert(vulne);
    //dao.formInsert(form);
```

DAO as follows.

```
@Repository("dao")
public class ScannerDAOImpl implements ScannerDAO {
@Autowired 
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public void scanInsert(scanInfoDTO scanresult) {
    mongoTemplate.insert(scanresult);

}

@Override
public void formInsert(formInfoDTO formresult) {
    mongoTemplate.insert(formresult);
}

@Override
public void vulListInsert(List<vulInfoDTO> vulresult) {
    mongoTemplate.insertAll(vulresult);
}
```

as a result in mongodb as follow.

[image]

now results separated different documents in mongodb collection.

so i want to merge results like this.. how can i do?
[image]

and one more question
how to insert multiple values about array in document filed on spring.
for examples, forminfo array in Second picture like this.
help me please...

Comment: Since you provided no code, we have no idea what your problem or level is... So try starting with the tutorials over a spring's: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data and MongoDB, insert or update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378978/spring-data-and-mongodb-insert-or-update)